# Remove custom event listener

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events

I'm listening to a custom event:

```
evt = new CustomEvent("fileThisEmail", {
  detail: {
    name: name,
    email: email,
    content: content
  }
});

window.dispatchEvent(evt);


window.addEventListener("fileThisEmail", this.handleFileEmail);
```

I need to remove the listener. I've tried:

```
window.removeEventListener("fileThisEmail", this.handleFileEmail);
window.removeEventListener("fileThisEmail");
```

but neither work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did the answer below worked for you?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The third argument to removeEventListener is mandatory. try this:

```
window.removeEventListener("fileThisEmail", this.handleFileEmail, false);
```

Comment: While the third param (`useCapture`) is supposed to be optional and defaults to false in modern browsers (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.removeEventListener), @harsh.prasad's code is correct and works for me using the example in the question.

Comment: Hmmm, not sure what to say. I'm getting event multiplying on each other every time the event listener is triggered. Any idea what the discrepancy could be?

Comment: I tried it from a raw event and it worked as shown above. I should probably also note that React is involved and I wonder if the event isn't being attach to the same thing. I'm going to accept this answer, because based on code above, it is correct.

Comment: @brandonhilkert I'm pretty familiar with React, so if you can make a jsfiddle or something that demonstrates I can take a look at it. Maybe post a new question, or find my email via my website.

Comment: @rfunduk new q here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26143612/react-custom-event-listener