# React custom event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, event-handling, jquery-events

I'm writing a Chrome extension that places a button next to the "reply" button of each email. And elsewhere on the page is the main React component. When the component loads, I add listeners to a custom event:

```
  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.listenForFileEmailEvent();
  },

  listenForFileEmailEvent: function() {
    window.addEventListener("fileThisEmail", this.handleFileEmail, false);
  },
```

I place the button in each email and setup the event:

```
  $(document).on("click", ".file-this-email", function(e) {
    var email = $(e.target).parents(".gs").find('.gD').first().attr("email");
    var name = $(e.target).parents(".gs").find('.gD').first().attr("name");
    var content = $(e.target).parents(".gs").find(".adP").first().text();

    evt = new CustomEvent("fileThisEmail", {
      detail: {
        name: name,
        email: email,
        content: content
      }
    });

    window.dispatchEvent(evt);
  });
```

The component is placed in the conversation view of each thread. So, naturally, if you go between the inbox, and then back to a conversion, another component is inserted. And thus the old listeners aren't removed, so multiple events fire the second time.

I tried to add the following before I setup the listener:

```
  listenForFileEmailEvent: function() {
    window.removeEventListener("fileThisEmail", this.handleFileEmail, false);
    window.addEventListener("fileThisEmail", this.handleFileEmail, false);
  },
```

But when I inspect the listener events after removing, and prioring to adding it again, it is still there.

So I think there are 2 questions, is there a better way to do this for a rogue button that will live outside the component? And if not, how can I ensure multiple events don't fire for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you'll find that `this.handleFileEmail` isn't necessarily the same function since you are adding/removing the component.

Try removing the listener in `componentWillUnmount` instead.

```
componentWillUnmount: function() {
  window.removeEventListener("fileThisEmail", this.handleFileEmail, false);
}
```

Comment: I tried that, except it doesn't seem to be triggered because it's going from Gmail's conversation view to their inbox view. So I'm not even sure what they do with those elements. Would you expect `componentWillUnmount` to be hit in that case?

Comment: Also, the component is being added to the conversation view, and that same component is the one listening for events from the buttons. So it seems to me as though it would be the same component. But maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: Hmm, so I think I'm confused about the setup. You have your own react component outside of gmail's ui, but you're inserting another react component into gmail's ui, right?

Comment: You know what, I think I see what you're saying now about it being a different component. I have a feeling you're right. That's the thing, because I can unmount it, I have a feeling it just mounts a new one every time I load the conversation view. Is this a problem for performance/memory usage, and do you think there's any way around this?

Comment: That should've read, "That's the thing, because I CAN'T unmount it..."

Comment: I'm going to accept this because it was the right answer in theory. It was a little challenging to do in Gmail, but with the combo of globals vars and then manually running `.unmountComponent()` to trigger the unmount worked.

Comment: Hey sorry SO doesn't notify me of comments for some reason. So yea, I think if gmail is just killing a component from the dom, then it might not have a chance to call it's componentWillUnmount. If you put in a log it should be obvious whether or not it does. Maybe instead of adding a component at all, just inject a dom node yourself? then you can handle it all by hand.